# Audacity will stop listing my Corsair wireless headphones as an output or input (mic) device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

My setup:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Asus Helios 300 laptop
Corsair wireless headphones
Displaylink D6000 dell dock

I will be happily using Audacity and listening to tracks though my Corsair wireless headphones. Then suddenly audacity won't play through the headphones any more, and does not list the headphones in the list of output devices and sound is directed to the external dock.

Other apps (e.g. smplayer, firefox) play through the headphones just fine

What does not work to restore audacity sound through headphones:

1. Restarting pulseaudio
2. Reinitializing ALSA
3. Rebooting
4. Rescanning for audio devices in audacity
5. Setting the output in the sound settings to the Corsair

What does work to restore audacity sound through headphones:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio

What is causing audacity to not detect the headphones any more? - and why such a drastic fix?